# Http API to Fetch Transaction ID

Tags: api, httpapi

Is it possible to get a wallet's most recent transaction id using http requests to https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getSignaturesForAddress` method. If you just want the most recent transaction you can use the `limit` filter. Example:

```
curl https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d $'
    {
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "id": 1,
      "method": "getSignaturesForAddress",
      "params": ["Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111",{"limit": 1}]
      }
  '
```

Ref: [getSignaturesForAddress](https://quicknode.com/docs/solana/getSignaturesForAddress)